# parameter is incorrect while generating word with POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

[image]I am trying to draw  jFreeChart in a word doc using apache POI ,but i am not able to do that .Here i what i have done by i dont know which api i have to use properly somebody please help.here i what i have done as of now,

```
      JFreeChart TotalActivityChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Total Activities", "Activities", "#Candidate", bar_chart_servlet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);

        /**---------------------------------- Appearance of chart for Total Activity------------------------------------ */
        // Adjust appearance (optional)
        TotalActivityChart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        TotalActivityChart.setAntiAlias(true);
        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) TotalActivityChart.getPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.DARK_GRAY, 0, 100, Color.GRAY));
        // set the range axis to display integers only...
        final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        final CategoryItemRenderer renderer = new CustomRenderer(new Paint[] { new Color(0x3D59AB), new Color(0x009ACD), new Color(0x104E8B), new Color(0x50A6C2) });
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);
        /**--------------------------------------- End of Appearance of Chart--------------------------------------- */
        int width = 800;
        int height = 240;
        ByteArrayOutputStream chart_out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(chart_out, TotalActivityChart, width, height);
        String pictureIdx = document.addPictureData(chart_out.toByteArray(), Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
        chart_out.close();
    int width = 800;
        int height = 240;
        ByteArrayOutputStream chart_out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(chart_out, TotalActivityChart, width, height);
        String pictureIdx = document.addPictureData(chart_out.toByteArray(), document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
        //document.createParagraph().createRun().addPicture(chart_out, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG,"my pic", Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200) );
        chart_out.close();



        run.addPicture(new FileInputStream(pictureIdx), Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, pictureIdx, Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200));


        // Setup the output
        String contentType="application/msword";
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+ "reportName" + ".docx\"");
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();           
        document.write(out);
```

can any one suggest how to add the picture in that word doc..Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you've got it generating a PNG image, is that right? If so, why not just add that to the right place in the word document using Apache POI?

Comment: how can i add can you please help??

Comment: i am getting filenootfound exception

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this block here:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream chart_out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(chart_out, TotalActivityChart, width, height);
String pictureIdx = document.addPictureData(chart_out.toByteArray(), document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
//document.createParagraph().createRun().addPicture(chart_out, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG,"my pic", Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200) );
chart_out.close();

run.addPicture(new FileInputStream(pictureIdx), Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, pictureIdx, Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200));
```

You're writing the chart picture into a byte array, but then trying to add some random file to the Word Document, which is never going to work!

Instead, pass the chart picture into the word document, which should be fine, something like:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream chart_out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(chart_out, TotalActivityChart, width, height);
String pictureIdx = document.addPictureData(chart_out.toByteArray(), document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
//document.createParagraph().createRun().addPicture(chart_out, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG,"my pic", Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200) );
chart_out.close();

byte[] chartPicture = chart_out.toByteArray();

run.addPicture(new ByteArrayInputStream(chartPicture), Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, pictureIdx, Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200));
```

The difference here is that after capturing the bytes of your picture, you then give those same bytes to POI to add into your document. You need to give the picture itself, otherwise it won't work!

Comment: see i posted the picture above

Comment: please see my commnents

Comment: You missed all the interesting POI bits out of your question, so who knows! The above fixes all the obvious problems in the code you posted. For anything else, try posting the remainder of your code, and also ensure you're using the latest copy of Apache POI

Comment: i have added the output i am using

Comment: why the parameter is not correct is coming can you help??

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue, i have changed poi version from 3.9 to 4.0.1
and it worked.